# Downloading gensim models behind a proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim, http-proxy

I am trying to download gensim pretrained word2vec models behind a proxy. I receive this error.

> urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

for the following code

```
import gensim.downloader as api
api.info()
```

I have already set proxy using

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://username:xxxxxx@myproxy.com
```

and have been successfully downloading packages using pip. Is there a way to add my proxy to gensim?

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line on terminal to download instead of run code:

```
export https_proxy=https://username:xxxxxx@myproxy.com 
python -m gensim.downloader --download text8
```